# Python Tkinter: ¿Hay alguna forma de ejecutar un messagebox muchas veces a la vez?

Tags: python, tkinter

Quiero hacer que se ejecuten varios messagebox a la vez, pero eso no sucede

Si por ejemplo, ejecuto esto:

```
from tkinter import *, messagebox

window = Tk()

for i in range(50):
    messagebox.showerror("Prueba", "Prueba")

window.mainloop()
```

Se ejecuta una a la vez, una vez cierre una se ejecuta la otra, quiero que se ejecuten todas a la vez  ¿Se puede? ¿Como?

Comment: Intenté ver si se podía cambiar algo en el código fuente para lograrlo. Pero no encuentro la forma. [Alguien tuvo la misma duda que vos en SO en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49032951/python-spawn-multiple-message-boxes-at-once) y confirmó mi sospecha. Me parece que la solución (nuevamente) es crear tu propio messagebox a partir de un toplevel.

Comment: Parece que los messagebox de Tkinter son poco personalizables.

Comment: Puedes crear tu propio msgbox usando la clase CommonDialog y añadiendo lo que necesites en tus pop-ups, haciendo que no sean modales. No se me ocurre porqué alguien querría hacer eso, pero....